# Device COM# is not currently available

Tags: php, usb, exec

I connected a USB modem with port settings below

[image]

I am using xampp to run my local server and the PHP exec() function returns

"Device COM7 is not currently available."

```
echo  exec('mode COM7: baud=9600 data=8 stop=1 parity=n xon=on');
```

Do I need to configure some settings of my computer?